# React Native KeyboardAvoidView Issue with TextInputs Nested in Components

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, keyboardavoidingview

I am very new to React Native (Not to react in general though), I am trying to leverage KeyboardAvoidView in React Native to prevent my inputs from being blocked by the keyboard. I created my own component consisting of a View, Image, TextInput, View, so that I can edit my inputs a bit easier, and on the page where I have them I have the whole page wrapped by the KeyboardAvoidView component, but it doesn't seem to find my the inputs and nothing works. If I use the KeyboardAvoidView in the custom component itself, it moves them all regardless of the TextInput used, and doesn't effect the rest of the page (Not the desired result), my question is: How can I get KeyboardAvoidView to work on the page itself and work with my custom component?

I have tried using the KeyboardAvoidView comp in my custom comp and on the page itself, I have the correct behaviour setup and styling, but it doesn't seem to like nested TextInputs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.